# Firefox not focusing window when opening link in existing window

Tags: html, firefox

I have a problem and I think the best thing is to describe it practically:

1. User is on the main window (this is properly called "main-window" via JavaScript: `self.name = "main-window";`)
2. User clicks on a link that opens in a new window
3. From the new window, user clicks on a link like: `<a href="..." target="main-window">`

The expected behaviour is the browser to focus on the main window ("main-window") and open the requested page (IE and Chrome do this correctly). Firefox opens the link in the main window, but doesn't focus on it. The result is that the user wonders why the link doesn't work since he doesn't realise that it opens on the window behind the current one.

Is this a known issue? Is there any solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried window.opener.focus()?